# KeyError in plotting with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dataset['YearsExperience'], dataset['salary'],'b.')
```

Here is the error I got :

```
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'salary'
```

Can some please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Please revise the question to format the text and code using the appropriate syntax styling. Thank you.

Comment: It appears `dataset` (DataFrame?) does not have a `salary` column.  Please include the output of `dataset.columns` in the question.

Comment: Check if you the column name is `Salary` (capital S) instead of  `salary`.